# Solution Verification: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}$ using ratio test

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I don't have the 'official' solution to this series so I wanted to verify mine.
\begin{equation*}
(s_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{n!(2n-n)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n!}
\end{equation*}
$\underline{\text{Claim:}}$ $(s_n)$ diverges.

$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$ Using ratio test:
\begin{equation*}
\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2(n+1))!}{((n+1)!)^2}}{(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n!}}\right|=\frac{\frac{(2(n+1))!}{((n+1)!)^2}}{\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n!}}=\frac{(2(n+1))!}{((n+1)!)^2}\cdot\frac{n!\cdot n!}{(2n)!}=\frac{n!\cdot n!\cdot (2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!(2n)!}
\end{equation*}
Further:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{n!\cdot n!\cdot (2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!(2n)!}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{4n^2+6n+2}{n^2+2n+1}=\frac{4+\frac{6}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}{1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}\rightarrow\frac{4+0+0}{1+0+0}=\frac{4}{1}=4.
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
C=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=4.
\end{equation*}
Since $C=4>1$: $(s_n)$ diverges.

Comment: Right. You could just have said that the limit of $a_n$ is not zero and so it diverges.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test